# How can i use remote function in vf page on click a button?

Tags: visualforce, remote-action

How can i use remote function in vf page on click a button ?

Comment: didn't you see example from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use JavaScript remoting in Visualforce to call methods in Apex controllers from JavaScript. Create pages with complex, dynamic behavior that isn’t possible with the standard Visualforce AJAX components.

Here’s a basic sample demonstrating how to use JavaScript remoting in your Visualforce pages.

```
  <apex:page controller="AccountRemoteController">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getAccountJS() 
{
    //get the values of input text and place into the variable.
    var accountNameJS = document.getElementById('accName').value;        
    AccountRemoteController.getAccount( accountNameJS, 
    function(result, event)
    {


        if (event.status) 
        {
            // demonstrates how to get ID for HTML and Visualforce tags
            document.getElementById("{!$Component.theBlock.thePageBlockSection.theFirstItem.accId}").innerHTML = result.Id;
            document.getElementById("{!$Component.theBlock.thePageBlockSection.theSecondItem.accNam}").innerHTML = result.Name;
        } 

    }, {escape:true});
}
</script>
Account Name :<input id="accName" type="text" />
<button onclick="getAccountJS()">Get Account</button>
<div id="errors-js"> </div>
<apex:pageBlock id="theBlock">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="thePageBlockSection" columns="2">
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theFirstItem">
            <apex:outputText id="accId"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="theSecondItem" >
            <apex:outputText id="accNam" />
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

```
 global class AccountRemoteController {
 public String accountName { get; set; }
public static Account account { get; set; }
//Default Constructor..
public AccountRemoteController() {

}

@RemoteAction
global static Account getAccount(String accountName) 
{
    account = [select id, name, phone, type, numberofemployees from Account where name = :accountName ];
    return account;
}
```

}